# .addClass() not working when using if-statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, addclass

I'm trying to add class by using Jquery if...

```
var i=0;     
 while(i<5){    
     var ll=$(".pages").eq(i).position().left;    
    console.log("ll="+ll+",i="+i);    
    i++;    
    if(ll=0){    
        $(".pages").eq(i).addClass("on");    
    };    
};
```

Comment: and where is the problem?

Comment: `if(ll=0){` this should be `if(ll==0){`. You're now assiging a variable which always returns true. Please read about [operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: @DarkBee That's not true, an assignment "returns" the assigned value, not `true`, except when `true` have been assigned.

Comment: assuming you meant to compare with `==`, why compare 11 to 0? they'll never be equal.

Answer (score 0):

you have an invalid `if()` statment using `=` which is an assignment operator not a comparison operator.

Instead of :

```
if(ll = 0)
```

Try:

```
if(ll === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write === instead of = here:

```
if(ll=0){
$(".pages").eq(i).addClass("on");
};
```

See here for more details: http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/